# mySQL: how many in a group

Tags: mysql

For testing purposes, here's a table (release) that looks similar to real data

```
release_id    group_id
------------------------------
  1            5
  2            5
  3            6
  4            7
```

For each release, i need to find how many releases there are in the group. The result set should look like this

```
release_id    total
------------------------------
  1            2
  2            2
  3            1
  4            1
```

In other words, release_id 1 belongs in group 5, and in group 5 there are 2 releases.... release_id 4 is in group 7 and there is only 1 release in group 7... and so on

I've try something like this

```
SELECT r.release_id, COUNT(r.group_id) total
FROM `release` r
GROUP BY (r.group_id)
```

But, i don't get exactly the expected result set.

Any ideas how to build the query?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    R.release_id, GC.cnt total
FROM 
    (SELECT group_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM release GROUP BY group_id) GC
    JOIN release R
    ON GC.group_id = R.group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using a `correlated subquery`:

```
select release_id, 
       (select count(*) from release r2 where r.group_id = r2.group_id) cnt
from release
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dinamic

```
select a.release_id, t.total 
(select group_id,COUNT(*) as total
FROM `release` ) t
inner join `release` r2
on t.group_id = r2.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got your count and group by reversed,

```
Select
r.group_id,
count (r.release_id)
from
release r
group by r.group_id
```